# Review of my Grade Calculator Database Design

Tags: mysql, relational-theory

I'm currently making a Grade Calculator which will be used by students of a university to calculate their own grades. I'd greatly appreciate feedback on the design I've made. Do you see any obvious flaws to it? Could I do something a better way? If you think there's room for improvement I'd be very interested in hearing and will act upon all suggestions pointed out me! I hope my Entity Relationship Diagram and its annotations is enough information to go on. Please let me know if anyone needs any clarification on anything. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Why `id` on every table, many of the lookup tables should just be a single column? The circular FK looks wrong, perhaps you shouldn't have `assignment -> unit` and perhaps `assignmentComponentLookup` and `unitComponentWeighting` should be merged?

Comment: Because my tables need an id? I only explicitly say what the id is for if it's a foreign key, primary keys I just have as id. And if I put them as a single column how am I supposed to have my lookup?

Comment: You just make the FK directly against the `name` column for example. Why do your tables *need* `id` columns, it's an unnecessary surrogate key?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need an id as if it will enable me to change the value easily. If I didn't have an incremental id and made the id the name of the table, then I would have to change everywhere I reference it. Having an incremental id will prevent this hassle.

Comment: Agreed, but only if you are likely to change them. But something like `GradeType` is not likely to change its abbreviation. It could have a `ShortName varchar(4)` primary key and `FullName varchar(30)`, for example `('BSc', 'Bachelor of Science')` then the FK can reference `BSc`, and you can change the `FullName` at will.